# My combobox doesn't show data from database

Tags: c#, combobox

my combo box needs to show data from my database but it shows empty.
here you have my code that i'm working on, visual studio dont show any error, but combobox shows empty, any tips ?

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=E:\Documents\basededadospap.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
            try
            {
                cn.Open();
                string query = "select * from fornecedor where nomefornecedor='" + comboBox1 + "'";
                SqlCommand createCommand = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
                SqlDataReader dr = createCommand.ExecuteReader();
                cn.Close();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any `Combobox` to bind in your code. You just assign a string to your textbox in a while loop.

Comment: i edited the code, that was an error, sorry nate

Comment: Still don't see any code that affect your combobox.

Comment: can you explain what are you saying please ?

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteReader` will return a reader which you then have to use to read back your results row by row, and populate your combo box accordingly.
For example, if you have a (non nullable) string column named "MyItem" in your fornecedor table, you would write something like this:

```
using (SqlDataReader dr = createCommand.ExecuteReader())
{
  int myItemOrdinal = dr.GetOrdinal("MyItem");
  List<object> comboBoxRows = new List<object>();
  while (dr.Read())
  {         
    string myItem = dr.GetString(myItemOrdinal);
    comboBoxRows.Add(myItem);
  }
}
comboBox1.BeginInvoke(() => comboBox1.Items.AddRange(comboBoxRows.ToArray()));
```

The last row populates the combo box on the UI thread, assuming reading the rows from the database is done on another thread (which is something you'd want to do to keep your UI responsive).